# I need to hide String "Level 2" after its done played

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i can't see text when I set winBox visibility to false, although I set condition that (i) should be equal to text length. if I remove it so it works but text still on screen. where is the fail and how I can hide the text after being played. 
thanks

```
private HBox winBox;
public void win(){
    String winMs = "Level 2";  
    for (int i = 0; i < winMs.toCharArray().length; i++){
        char letter = winMs.charAt(i);
        Text winTxt = new Text(String.valueOf(letter)); //Node
        winBox.getChildren().add(winTxt);
        winTxt.setFont(Font.font(48));
        winTxt.setOpacity(0.05);
        FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1), winTxt); 
        fade.setToValue(1);
        fade.setDelay(Duration.seconds(i * 0.1));
        fade.play();
        if(i == winMs.toCharArray().length)
            winBox.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key here is `setOnFinished`. Like @Fabian said, use it outside the loop, that way it catches when the final fade finishes.

```
fade.setOnFinished((event) -> {
    winBox.setVisible(false); 
});
```

> Full Code:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication183 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        HBox winBox = new HBox();

        String winMs = "Level 2";

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            FadeTransition fade = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < winMs.toCharArray().length; i++) {
                char letter = winMs.charAt(i);
                Text winTxt = new Text(String.valueOf(letter)); //Node
                winBox.getChildren().add(winTxt);
                winTxt.setFont(Font.font(48));
                winTxt.setOpacity(0.05);
                fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1), winTxt);
                fade.setToValue(1);
                fade.setDelay(Duration.seconds(i * 0.1));
                fade.play();
            }

            fade.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> winBox.setVisible(false));
        });

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(btn);

        VBox root = new VBox(winBox, stackPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Should only be done on the last one through... Declaring `fade` outside of the loop would help prevent the check in every loop iteration.

Comment: Accept the answer as correct if it helped you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have following condition

```
if(i == winMs.toCharArray().length - 1)
    winBox.setVisible(false);
```

Instead of

```
if(i == winMs.toCharArray().length)
        winBox.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: still the same can't see text

Comment: You need to set visibility to true if you want to see the text

Comment: After you come out of the for loop fade is done playing and you can set the visibility to false. So there is no need of the 'if' condition inside loop

Comment: when I do that I can't see text from beginning. I am thinking now maybe fade takes some times to be done played java will check the condition where visibility is false before that so that is why I can't see text . maybe I need to set some delay before visibility come false.

Comment: Can you try setting visibility to true inside loop before fade is played ?